How can I use range-selection in ag-grid in angular? As the feature comes under enterprise version, how can I achieve it in community version itself?
I am using ag-grid in our angular application, and the range-selection option is not working since the feature comes only under enterprise version. But i want to achieve it in community version itself. or is there any other way I can do it? Please share your responses.
I have tried an alternative solution for nz-table from ng-zorro, but that didn't work for me!
